# Multilanguages in soap response

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I am using nusoap library, When I send chinese language as input the response does not support the chinese language and resulting output is ????.

Please help how to get the chinese language in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are instantiating a nusoap try it like this:

```
$nuso = new nusoap_client('http://test.com/');
$nuso->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$nuso->decode_utf8 = false;
$res = $nuso->call('testFunction');
```

The issue seems to be when declaring the `decode_utf8` parameter as true.

Hope it works.